# Gtk button weird text color

Tags: gtk, gtk#, gtk2

I'm trying to show Gtk button inside a event box with a defined background color. In the image below, there are two buttons:

- The left one is packed in the EventBox with a background color
- The right one is placed in a standard HBox.

[image]

It seems that the left button takes part of that background to render the antialias text.

Somebody knows how can make the left button text to look like the right one?

Comment: This is possibly because the alpha on the Color that is used to render text is not 100%, i.e. it's showing background colour through. If you really get stuck you could try drawing a mask around the button with Cairo on the expose event of the EventBox. That's just working around the problem rather than solving it though.

Comment: PS -- what OS are you using? And which windowing engine?